# Can we ask questions related to Programming?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask questions about programming questions on Pytorch, TensorFlow, or any deep learning frameworks??

Answer (score 3):

No.

General programming issues are off-topic here. For example, if you have an exception/bug/error in your source code or you don't know how to use a certain library/API, then that's off-topic. If you have this type of question, the most appropriate site is probably Stack Overflow (or Data Science SE).

However, if you want to understand how a certain concept/algorithm/model is implemented, then you can ask questions about that because that's more a conceptual question. [Here is an example of such a question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/20803/2444). (But, please, try to ask a specific and clear question that explains what you don't really understand, so that to facilitate the answerer's life).

[Our on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) actually states these things explicitly, so I suggest that you read or at least skim through our on-topic page again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm personally in favor of this, but the overall consensus is that we should focus on theory, as opposed to implementation.

(We haven't historically had good response to programming or implementation questions, so the argument for leaving those to overflow and other stacks is strong.)